# Searching and Counting Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to search data based on month and year. Then, it will count the same id for `Book_id`.

I have problems to count the `Book_id` for monthly. This query will count for entire records including monthly, which is not the result I want.

```
$res2 = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT Date_borrow, Book_name as nmBook,   Book_id as b_id,  count(Book_name) AS count 

FROM transaksi

GROUP BY nmBook

HAVING count > 1 

ORDER BY COUNT DESC ");

$rowss = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would transaksi table have book_name in it?

Comment: Because I want to display the output of the book_name @DrewPierce

Comment: I know but it is de-normalized data and can create many problems

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a shot at it not knowing you complete data model

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date_borrow, Book_name as nmBook,   Book_id as b_id,  
count(Book_name) AS count 
FROM transaksi
GROUP BY nmBook
HAVING count > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

Should be:

```
SELECT Date_borrow, Book_name as nmBook,  Book_id as b_id,  
count(Book_name) AS counter
FROM transaksi
GROUP BY Book_name,Date_borrow,book_id
HAVING count(Book_name) > 1 
ORDER BY `counter` DESC;
```

DISTINCT and GROUP BY are mutually exclusive: Once you use GROUP BY, apply either a function on all the fields or add the fields in the GROUP BY.

HAVING COUNT(Book_name): COUNT needs a parameter, so book_name in this case since that is the same as in your SELECT statement.

Use of just created alias in ORDER BY: Test that. Could be that you need to use COUNT(book_name) there too.

Use of reserved word "COUNT" as alias: Avoid the use of any terms sounding like functions or code in table names, column names, function names etc. Invent your own naming standard which avoids this use of (possibly) reserved key words.